# How to overwrite a string in a file but keep the remainder of the string in tact

Tags: bash

struggling with this maybe somebody has an idea

I just want to overwrite the amount of characters of a given output over the original string but keep the remainder untouched

example 
original string

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000
```

new string

```
sometexthere00000000000000000000000
```

looked a various ways but the all seem to replace the whole line or look for certain strings to match

Answer (score 2):

`Sed` would be very helpful.

For example you want to replace the first 12 characters with `sometexthere`, you can write

```
>>> echo 0000000000000000000000000000000000 | sed -E 's/^.{12}/sometexthere/'
sometexthere0000000000000000000000
```

**What it does?**

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `.{12}` `.` Matches anything, combined with `{12}`, it matches 12 any characters.

---

You can also use parameter substitution, for example

```
$ echo ${val/00000/hello}
hello000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.` in a regex to match any character (just once) and a `^` to match the start of a line.

Not knowing the exact format of the file etc, here is an example using sed to edit a string outputted by echo:

`echo "00000000000000000000000000000000000" | sed 's/^.........../aaaaaaaaaaaa/'`

Answer (score 0):

Full bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# original="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
original="00000000000000000000000000000000000"
overwrite="sometexthere"
modified=${overwrite}${original:${#overwrite}} # append overwrite with substring of original from overwrite's length to the end

echo ${modified}
```